# how to override default theme of bootstrap in flask_bootstrap environment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-bootstrap

I am making an application by using flask and flask_bootstrap.

I choose a theme from [this web site](http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/). You can edit the variables of that theme online to customize it. And at last you can download the edit result as `bootstrap.css` to your local.

Now I have to copy&paste this bootstrap.css to `venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/static/css` and overwrite the original one. Only by this way, I can keep my website working with error message. But every time I upgrade the `flask_bootstrap` in pip virtual environment, I have to copy&paste the css file once again. I feel it boring and I believe there should be a solution.

I tried to put the customized site-generated `bootstrap.css` in my own `static` folder and add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='theme_page.css') }}" />` reference. But a batch of error messages pop, like: `"GET /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 404 -`. I know this is because in the customized css file, there is reference to the font folder but obviously that my own `static` folder is not the one which locates in `venv.../flask_bootstrap/static` and really include `/fonts`.

So any good suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I did was

- take out the lines including a reference to external files (so the fonts) from the custom `bootstrap.css`, and
- include them in my base template in `{% block styles %}` with:

```css
<style>
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        src: url('{{ url_for("bootstrap.static", filename="fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot") }}');
        src: url('{{ url_for("bootstrap.static", filename="fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") }}') format('embedded-opentype'), 
             url('{{ url_for("bootstrap.static", filename="fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") }}') format('woff2'), 
             url('{{ url_for("bootstrap.static", filename="fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") }}') format('woff'), 
             url('{{ url_for("bootstrap.static", filename="fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") }}') format('truetype'), 
             url('{{ url_for("bootstrap.static", filename="fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") }}') format('svg');
    }
</style>
```

This will look for the fonts in the original place, that can be upgraded.

Or you can put them in a template and use something like:

```html
<style>
    {% include "_bootstrap_fonts.css" %}
</style>
```